# CCTray WinLogin authentication using ldap security

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cctray

I have CC.net (v. 1.8.3) and CCTray (also v. 1.8.3) installed and LDAP security set up. However, when I add my build server to CCTray and select WinLogin authentication, no builds show up, and I get a login failed notification in the CCNet logs.

If I change the authentication to username/password, it works as I'd expect, however, when closing and restarting CCTray, builds show up as unknown status until I go into configuration to give things a kick. I'd also like to get the AD authentication working without manually specifying username and password because we have a custom build dashboard already using AD auth and I could secure everything through configuration as I should be able to.

Anyone have any ideas or can anyone confirm that they've been able to get AD authentication to work through CCTray or through the CCNet APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinLogin authentication is broken in CCTray. I'm only able to authenticate (not without problems), if the service is executed as a console application (ccnet.exe). I've never had success with the ccnet windows service (ccservice.exe). I've tried both 'via dashboard' and '.NET remoting' options - no difference.